# What's a better way of managing large Haskell records?

Tags: haskell, records

Replacing fields names with letters, I have cases like this:

```
data Foo = Foo { a :: Maybe ...
               , b :: [...]
               , c :: Maybe ...
               , ... for a lot more fields ...
               } deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

instance Writer Foo where
  write x = maybeWrite a ++
            listWrite  b ++
            maybeWrite c ++
            ... for a lot more fields ...

parser = permute (Foo
                   <$?> (Nothing, Just `liftM` aParser)
                   <|?> ([], bParser)
                   <|?> (Nothing, Just `liftM` cParser)
                   ... for a lot more fields ...

-- this is particularly hideous
foldl1 merge [foo1, foo2, ...]
merge (Foo a b c ...seriously a lot more...)
      (Foo a' b' c' ...) = 
        Foo (max a a') (b ++ b') (max c c') ...
```

What techniques would allow me to better manage this growth?

In a perfect world `a`, `b`, and `c` would all be the same type so I could keep them in a list, but they can be many different types. I'm particularly interested in any way to fold the records without needing the massive patterns.

I'm using this large record to hold the different types resulting from [permutation parsing the vCard format](https://github.com/rcampbell/vcard/blob/master/VCard.hs).

**Update**

I've implemented both the [generics](https://github.com/rcampbell/vcard/blob/b377d690854ac088ae8fba078971ac732b08cfb8/VCard.hs#L115-L151) and the [foldl](https://github.com/rcampbell/vcard/blob/14fb1c91df249ec9aa21ac5cbfe967d7b7a9757d/VCard.hs#L109-L141) approaches suggested below. They both work, and they both reduce [three large field lists](https://github.com/rcampbell/vcard/blob/da4dc58770451f026f871b2ec27c4f5f75bcba54/VCard.hs#L112-L174) to one.

Comment: Do the record fields need to be named (could `Foo` be something else then a record)?

Comment: This smell of XY problem. Maybe the solution is to not have that kind of `Foo` at all, but to make that judgement we *must* be given information about the problem that `Foo` has to solve.

Comment: Seems like a use case for datatype-generic programming, perhaps using a generics library like "generics-sop".

Comment: @Bakuriu - Good point. I've added a note about the problem I'm trying to solve. Basically the record is in place to collect the different types resulting from [permutation parsing the vCard format](https://github.com/rcampbell/vcard/blob/master/VCard.hs). In the code I've linked to you can see how it's getting unwieldy. I don't know how certain I can be that the types will only be lists and Maybes - it's an early and rough impl - but perhaps the fact that there are only two types can be taken advantage of somehow...

Answer (score 5):

Datatype-generic programming techniques can be used to transform all the fields of a record in some "uniform" sort of way.

Perhaps all the fields in the record implement some typeclass that we want to use (the typical example is `Show`). Or perhaps we have another record of "similar" shape that contains functions, and we want to apply each function to the corresponding field of the original record.

For these kinds of uses, the [generics-sop](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop) library is a good option. It expands the default Generics functionality of GHC with extra type-level machinery that provides analogues of functions like [`sequence`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop-0.2.1.0/docs/Generics-SOP.html#t:HSequence) or [`ap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop-0.2.1.0/docs/Generics-SOP.html#t:HAp), but which work over all the fields of a record.

Using generics-sop, I tried to create a slightly less verbose version of your `merge` funtion. Some preliminary imports:

```
{-# language TypeOperators #-}
{-# language DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# language TypeFamilies #-}
{-# language DataKinds #-}

import Control.Applicative (liftA2)
import qualified GHC.Generics as GHC
import Generics.SOP
```

A [helper](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop-0.2.1.0/docs/Generics-SOP.html#v:Fn) function that lifts a binary operation to a form useable by the functions of generics-sop:

```
fn_2' :: (a -> a -> a) -> (I -.-> (I -.-> I)) a -- I is simply an Identity functor
fn_2' = fn_2 . liftA2
```

A general merge function that takes a vector of operators and works on any single-constructor record that derives `Generic`:

```
merge :: (Generic a, Code a ~ '[ xs ]) => NP (I -.-> (I -.-> I)) xs -> a -> a -> a 
merge funcs reg1 reg2 =
    case (from reg1, from reg2) of 
        (SOP (Z np1), SOP (Z np2)) -> 
            let npResult  = funcs `hap` np1 `hap` np2
            in  to (SOP (Z npResult))
```

[`Code`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop-0.2.1.0/docs/Generics-SOP.html#t:Code) is a type family that returns a type-level list of lists describing the structure of a datatype. The outer list is for constructors, the inner lists contain the types of the fields for each constructor.

The `Code a ~ '[ xs ]` part of the constraint says "the datatype can only have one constructor" by requiring the outer list to have exactly one element.

The `(SOP (Z _)` pattern matches extract the (heterogeneus) vector of field values from the record's generic representation. [`SOP`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop-0.2.1.0/docs/Generics-SOP.html#t:SOP) stands for "sum-of-products".

A concrete example:

```
data Person = Person
    {
        name :: String
    ,   age :: Int
    } deriving (Show,GHC.Generic)

instance Generic Person -- this Generic is from generics-sop

mergePerson :: Person -> Person -> Person
mergePerson = merge (fn_2' (++) :* fn_2' (+) :* Nil)
```

The `Nil` and `:*` constructors are used to build the vector of operators (the type is called [`NP`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop-0.2.1.0/docs/Generics-SOP.html#t:NP), from n-ary product). If the vector doesn't match the number of fields in the record, the program won't compile.

**Update.** Given that the types in your record are highly uniform, an alternative way of creating the vector of operations is to define instances of an auxiliary typeclass for each field type, and then use the [`hcpure`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop-0.2.1.0/docs/Generics-SOP.html#v:hpure) function:

```
class Mergeable a where
    mergeFunc :: a -> a -> a

instance Mergeable String where
    mergeFunc = (++)

instance Mergeable Int where
    mergeFunc = (+)

mergePerson :: Person -> Person -> Person
mergePerson = merge (hcpure (Proxy :: Proxy Mergeable) (fn_2' mergeFunc))
```

The [`hcliftA2`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop-0.2.1.0/docs/Generics-SOP.html#v:hcliftA2) function (that combines `hcpure`, `fn_2` and `hap`) could be used to simplify things further.

Comment: I've [implemented this approach](https://github.com/rcampbell/vcard/blob/b377d690854ac088ae8fba078971ac732b08cfb8/VCard.hs#L115-L151) in a `generics` branch to compare against the foldl one.

Comment: @rcampbell I've updated the code to simplify a few things.

Answer (score 2):

Some suggestions:

(1) You can use the **RecordWildCards** extension to automatically
unpack a record into variables. Doesn't help if you need to unpack
two records of the same type, but it's a useful to keep in mind.
Oliver Charles has a nice blog post on it: [(link)](https://ocharles.org.uk/blog/posts/2014-12-04-record-wildcards.html)

(2) It appears your example application is performing a fold over the records.
Have a look at Gabriel Gonzalez's [foldl](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/foldl-1.2.1/docs/Control-Foldl.html#t:Fold) package. There is also a blog post: [(link)](http://www.haskellforall.com/2013/08/foldl-100-composable-streaming-and.html)

Here is a example of how you might use it with a record like:

```
data Foo = Foo { _a :: Int, _b :: String }
```

The following code computes the maximum of the `_a` fields and the
concatenation of the `_b_` fields.

```
 import qualified Control.Foldl as L
 import Data.Profunctor

 data Foo = Foo { _a :: Int, _b :: String }
  deriving (Show)

 fold_a :: L.Fold Foo Int
 fold_a = lmap _a (L.Fold max 0 id)

 fold_b :: L.Fold Foo String
 fold_b = lmap _b (L.Fold (++) "" id)

 fold_foos :: L.Fold Foo Foo
 fold_foos = Foo <$> fold_a <*> fold_b

 theFoos = [ Foo 1 "a", Foo 3 "b", Foo 2 "c" ]

 test = L.fold fold_foos theFoos
```

Note the use of the Profunctor function `lmap` to extract out
the fields we want to fold over. The expression:

```
L.Fold max 0 id
```

is a fold over a list of Ints (or any Num instance), and therefore:

```
lmap _a (L.Fold max 0 id)
```

is the same fold but over a list of `Foo` records where we use `_a`
to produce the Ints.

Comment: I've [implemented this approach](https://github.com/rcampbell/vcard/blob/14fb1c91df249ec9aa21ac5cbfe967d7b7a9757d/VCard.hs#L109-L141) in a `foldl` branch to compare against the generics one.