# Is there a way to apply Maybe constructor to each field of record with generics?

Tags: haskell, generics, types

I have two data types and the second one is the copy of first, but with Maybe on each field.

```
data A = {a :: Int, b :: String}
data B = {c :: Maybe Int, d :: Maybe String}
```

Is there a way to make a functions

```
f :: A -> B
g :: B -> A -> A
```

without any knowledge about fields itself? (if value of first argument is nothing `g` will take default value from second argument)

Comment: I assume this is so you can have optional arguments to a function. I would instead have it take an A and provide a default A that the caller can pass to your function after optionally modifying it using record update syntax.

Comment: The B data type is used as isomorphism to yaml config file, where some options could be missing. But program should work with easy and safe A type. B shouldn't be used for anything except converting it to A.

Comment: You could use https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yaml-0.8.18.1/docs/Data-Yaml.html#v:.-33--61- or https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yaml-config-0.4.0/docs/Data-Yaml-Config.html#v:lookupDefault or https://hackage.haskell.org/package/config-value-0.5/docs/Config-Lens.html instead? ._.

Comment: The first thing is compile-time, so I couldn't use different default configs for example. The second thing produces a lot of code on every use of config. And lenses are complicated and it will take a lot of time to understand them and there are advices not to use them from many haskell developers.

Comment: Also Yaml.Config is read-only.

Comment: I guess this is the same as asking if there is a type-level `fmap` function, that maps a type constructor over a (product) type? Something like `data B = TypeFMap Maybe A`.

Comment: @chepner, not exactly. This could be achieved by Template Haskell in compile-time. What I need is a real-time functions to convert value from one type to another. I can do it by hand, but I don't want to duplicate same field declarations four times. I need `f x = B {c = Just $ a x, d = Just $ b x}` and same `g` but generated automatically using generics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done with [generics-sop](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop-0.2.2.0), a library that extends the default Generics machinery of GHC.

"generics-sop" can take a regular record and deduce a generic representation for it. This representation has a type parameter that wraps every field, and the library allows Applicative [sequence-like](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop-0.2.2.0/docs/Generics-SOP.html#v:hsequence) operations across the record fields.

```
{-# language TypeOperators #-}
{-# language DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# language TypeFamilies #-}
{-# language DataKinds #-}

import qualified GHC.Generics as GHC
import Generics.SOP

data A = A {a :: Int, b :: String} deriving (Show,GHC.Generic)

instance Generic A -- this Generic is from generics-sop

defaulty :: (Generic a, Code a ~ '[ xs ]) => NP Maybe xs -> a -> a 
defaulty maybes r = case (from r) of
    SOP (Z np) -> let result = hliftA2 (\m i -> maybe i I m) maybes np
                  in  to (SOP (Z result))

main :: IO ()
main = do
   print $ defaulty (Nothing :* Just "bar" :* Nil) (A 99 "foo")
```

`Nothing :* Just "bar" :* Nil` is a generic representation that matches the list of fields in the original record definition. Notice that each field in the representation is wrapped in `Maybe`.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38248692/whats-a-better-way-of-managing-large-haskell-records/38251692#38251692) for another example of generics-sop.

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

data R f = R { a :: f Int, b :: f String, c :: f Char }

newtype I a = I { unI :: a }

fromMaybeI :: I a -> Maybe a -> I a
fromMaybeI a Nothing = a
fromMaybeI _ (Just a) = I a

fromMaybeR :: R I -> R Maybe -> R I
fromMaybeR ri rm =
  R (go a) (go b) (go c)
  where
    go :: (forall f. R f -> f a)  -> I a
    go x = fromMaybeI (x ri) (x rm)
```

`R Maybe` is the record with Maybe values, `R I` is the record with concrete values.

Using RankNTypes reduces the amount of boilerplate code in `fromMaybeR`.

One downside is that you have use `I` and `unI` to construct and
access the field values.