# Apply a function to all fields in a record at the type-level

Tags: haskell, types

Is there a way to do the following in the type system easily?

```
data Product = Product {
    id :: ProductId
  , name :: Text
  , sku :: SKU, quantity :: Int
  , description :: Maybe Text
  }

data Omittable a = Omit | Present a
type ProductWithOmittableFields = Omittable Product

-- ProductWithOmittableFields is now equivalent to:\
--
-- data ProductWithOmittableFields = ProductWithOmmitableFields { 
--     id :: Omittable ProductId
--    ,name :: Omittable Text
--    ,sku : : Omittable SKU
--    ,quantity :: Omittable Int
--    ,desciption :: Omittable (Maybe Text)
--  }
```

It’s basically some sort of a container (functor?) which is applied to every field of a record at the type-level.

Is this idea better represented with an extensible records library?

**edit** the use case is that we will get a `ProductWithOmittableFields` from the UI layer, representing the set of fields that have been changed by the user; we will get a `Product` from the DB, and we will merge them to get the new value of `Product`

Comment: "Is this idea better represented with an extensible records library?" There is a library called "generics-sop" that lets you do something like it. See these other questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39020787/is-there-a-way-to-apply-maybe-constructor-to-each-field-of-record-with-generics and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38248692/whats-a-better-way-of-managing-large-haskell-records

Answer (score 5):

A possible way:

```
import Control.Functor.Identity

data Product k = Product {
    id :: k ProductId
  , name :: k Text
  , sku :: k SKU
  , quantity :: k Int
  , description :: k (Maybe Text)
  }

data Omittable a = Omit | Present a
type ProductWithOmittableFields = Product Omittable
type ProductWithRegularFields = Product Identity
```

Examples:

```
testOmit :: ProductWithOmittableFields
testOmit = Product
     { id = Present someProductId
     , name = Omit
     ... }

testReg :: ProductWithRegularFields
testReg = Product
     { id = Identity someProductId
     , name = Identity someText
     ... }
```

This approach only has the minor inconvenience of wrapping each field with an `Identity` in the regular case.

Comment: What's the easiest way to get a `ProductWithRegularFields` from a `Product Identity` at the value-level (i.e. runtime)?

Comment: @SaurabhNanda You don't have to do anything, they are exactly the same type. Above I used type synonyms `type T = ` instead of declaring new types `data T = ...`.

Comment: let me rephrase. How to get a `Product` value where each field is NOT an `Identity x`?

Comment: In this approach, every field has type `k x` for some `k`. It can't have type `x`.

Comment: @SaurabhNanda chi is right. On the other hand, an `Identity a` value *is* an `a` value, except for the annoying `Identity` wrapper. You can either pretend the wrapper isn't there while using `(<$>)` and `(<*>)` to manipulate the underlying value, or get rid of the wrapper with `runIdentity`.

Comment: @SaurabhNanda Indeed, you can convert any `x` into `Identity x` using the constructor `Identity :: x -> Identity x`, and you can convert things in the other direction using the inverse function `runIdentity :: Identity x -> x`. It _is_ a bit inconvenient to have to wrap/unwrap things, but it can be done.

Comment: Can `runIdentity` be used to convert a `Product Identity` (from your example) to a `Product` (from my original question)? Basically, what's the easiest way to go from `{id :: Identity ProductID, name :: Identity Text} -> {id :: ProductID, name :: Text}`

Comment: You can define (or derive) a `Functor` instance for `Product`, then define `identity2regular = fmap runIdentity`.

Comment: (@SaurabhNanda) @chepner This `Product` has fields with types different from each other, though, which rules `Functor` out. It seems to me that having with two separate `Product` types might end up being more annoying overall than just removing the `Identity` wrappers at usage point... unless, perhaps, if you take a generics-based approach, like danidiaz suggests in a comment to the question.

Comment: Edited the question to give usage context. See if that helps clarify the answer.

Comment: @SaurabhNanda, I think chi's approach is likely the one you want. You can write a function `mapProd :: (forall a . j a -> k a) -> Product j -> Product k` to, for instance, "upgrade" `Product Identity` to `Product Omittable`. Your actual use case may call for a similar zipping function: `zipProd :: (forall a . j a -> k a -> m a) -> Product j -> Product k -> Product m`.