# Build more advanced generic parser

Tags: haskell, generic-programming

ok, here is a continuation of my previous question [(Generically) Build Parsers from custom data types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42583838/generically-build-parsers-from-custom-data-types/42586193#42586193). I took the advice and decided to build my parsers with generic-sop and all was going fine until now.

I need to expand my implementation a little bit so more complicated situations can be dealt with. Namely, consider these two `data` definitions, where `B` is built on top of `A`:

```
data A = A String Int

data B = B A Double
```

In order to generically parse all `data` structures, I define the following `class`:

```
class HasSimpleParser f where
  getSimpleParser :: Parser f

class Parsable f where
  getParser :: Parser f

class GenericallyParsable f where
  getGenericParser :: Parser f
```

The primitive types such as `Int, String, Double` etc can be made into instances of `HasSimpleParser` easily. Then I make data structure such as `A` an instance of `Parsable` by doing

```
instance (Generic r, Code r ~ '[xs], All HasSimpleParser xs) => Parsable r where
  getParser = to . SOP. Z <$> hsequence (hcpure (Proxy @HasSimpleParser) getSimpleParser)
```

I introduce the class `GenericallyParsable` to parse data structure like `B`. So I do the following:

```
 instance (Generic r, Code r ~ '[xs], All Parsable xs) => GenericallyParsable r where
  getGenericParser = to . SOP. Z <$> hsequence (hcpure (Proxy @Parsable) getParser)
```

The last pieces of the puzzle are the parsing functions:

```
parseA :: InputStream ByteString -> IO A
parseA = parseFromStream (getGenericParser @A)

parseB :: InputStream ByteString -> IO B
parseB = parseFromStream (getGenericParser @B)
```

However, the code won't compile and I got the following error:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘'['[Char, [Char]]]’ with ‘'[]’
    arising from a use of ‘getGenericParser’
• In the first argument of ‘parseFromStream’, namely
    ‘(getGenericParser @A)’
  In the expression: parseFromStream (getGenericParser @A)
  In an equation for ‘parseA’:
      parseA = parseFromStream (getGenericParser @A)
```

So how should I modify the code to work?

Comment: Why three identical classes?

Comment: My logic was `HasSimpleParser` for primitive data types, `Parsable` for records with only fields that are primitive data types and `GenericallyParsable` for composite data types.

Answer (score 2):

I think the `GenericallyParsable` typeclass is not necessary.

Just define a `HasSimpleParser` instance for `A` that piggybacks on `Parsable`:

```
instance HasSimpleParser A where
    getSimpleParser = getParser
```

If you end up declaring many instances of this type for your records, you can streamline it a little using [`{-# language DefaultSignatures #-}`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#default-method-signatures) and changing the definition of `HasSimpleParser` to

```
class HasSimpleParser c where
    getSimpleParser :: Parser c
    default getSimpleParser :: Parsable c => Parser c
    getSimpleParser = getParser
```

Now in the record instances you would only have to write:

```
instance HasSimpleParser A
```

---

In fact, perhaps even the distinction between `HasSimpleParser` and `Parsable` in unnecessary. A single `HasParser` typeclass with instances for both basic and composite types would be enough. The default implementation would use generics-sop and require a `(Generic r, Code r ~ '[xs], All HasParser xs)` constraint.

```
class HasParser c where
    getParser :: Parser c
    default getParser :: (Generic c, Code c ~ '[xs], All HasParser xs) => Parser c
    getParser = ...generics-sop code here...
```

Comment: Gist with full example: https://gist.github.com/danidiaz/2a2ddb5dc120718012eced28200b56d5

Comment: thanks a bunch. Let me play with the gist a little bit and come back to you if I end up with more questions!

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much. Though there is another tiny complication that needs to be taken care of: What about lists in the record? For example, `data C = Bool [Int]`? And possibly even more  complicated: `data D = [C] Double`? I guess I need sth. like `instance (HasParser c) => HasParser [c]` but I'm not able to come up with the implementation.

Comment: @user2812201 It depends on the type of your parser and on how lists are serialized (extra `\NUL`?). Does your parser have an `Alternative` instance? If so, perhaps you could write something like megaparsec's `manyTill :: Alternative m => m a -> m end -> m [a]`

Comment: my `String`, `Bool`, `Double` etc all end with a '\NUL'. Is it possible to use `manyTill` or `many` combinators?

Comment: @user2812201 On the wire, what differentiaties a list of two ints from a register with two int fields?

Comment: Here is a little backgroud: I need to parse a stream of responses from the server. In the stream, every response is preceded by an id, which is an integer. I just parse the id first and then call the corresponding parser. So I guess the answer to your question is nothing differentiates the two responses, and I have to keep track by hand.